# how to export qc test cases associated with requirements filtered by specified requirement fileds to excel?

Tags: excel, export, requirements, hp-quality-center

steps are as follows,

1. get requirements filtered by specified requirement fields,for example que_no,child_no.
   actually,these requirement fields are associated with CQ fields.
2. export test cases coveraged by above requirements to excel. 
   test case include test name,description,designer,status,step name,step description,expected result...

anyone can tell me how to export those test cases to excel using vb script?

Comment: Which version of QC are you using?

Comment: I use Quality Center 9.2